# Close-packing of equal spheres of ABCDABCDABCD

Tags: geometry

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres) said that there are two lattices that can create high density, cubic close-packed from ABCABC layers and hexagonal close-packed from ABABAB layers that can form octahedral and tetrahedral voids. Is it possible to create other close-packed from ABCDABCDABCD? What kind of void that would be made from ABCDABCDABCD layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We really have only three possible placements of the layers of spheres, because the centers of spheres in any layer project into only one of three distinct sets of points on the "ground".  We label those three sets A, B, C and that's it.  No more.

What we *can* have is orderings among A, B, C other than the simplest ones you quote.  For example, there could be ABACABAC where you have all three sets of locations but not equally represented (e.g. more A's than B's), an arrangement called double hexagonal close-packed. [This presentation](https://msestudent.com/dhcp/9) explains the double hexagonal close-packed arrangement and identifies lanthanum as a prototypical example.  [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanum) also lists this structure for lanthanum.  The structure of samarium, discussed [here](https://www.atomic-scale-physics.de/lattice/struk/c19.html), involves a more complex packing (ABCBCACAB).

Comment: Could you give an answer also to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572701/space-groups-of-close-packed-structures ?